# Volume of a cone r = 5 height 10

Tags: calculus, integration

So I have acone with radius 5 and height 10. I am trying to find it's volume.

I set up similar trinagles to find a function for the radius so I can get a "slice " and then compute the integral from 0 to 10

$$(10-y)/10 = r/5$$

$$r = \frac{10-y}{2}$$

$$V = \int_0^{10} \pi * r^2$$

$$\pi \int_0^{10}  *(\frac{10-y}{2})^2$$

$$(\frac{10-y}{2})^2 = y^2/4 -5y + 25$$

$$\pi \int_0^{10}  y^2/4 -5y + 25$$

This is wrong, I have odne it many times, why?

Comment: Why are you using $10-y$ in your equation?  Is there any reason to not use $y$ directly?

Comment: Because 10 is the height and y is how high up I am so 10-y gives me the location.

Comment: More directly then:  if the range of $y$ is 0 to 10, and we compute the value of $10-y$, what range of values do we get?

Comment: I just used 10-y because the book did, I don't really know why.

Comment: The integral is right.

Comment: It could use a $dy$ at the end of each integral, just for form's sake...

Comment: For the sake of clarity, your volume integral that you started with has $r \in [0, 10]$, where it should actually be $r \in [0, 5]$ and then $y \in [0, 10]$ when you change variables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your calculation, as far as you took it, is right, you want
$$\pi\int_0^{10}\left(\frac{y^2}{4}-5y+25\right)\,dy.$$
For the integration, an antiderivative is $\frac{y^3}{12}-\frac{5y^2}{2}+25y$.

When you "plug in," the last two terms cancel, and you get $\frac{1000}{12}$. Multiply by $\pi$, simplify, and you get $\frac{250\pi}{3}$.

The work is a little simpler if you put the cone **point down**, with the apex   at the origin.

Then your similar triangle method gives that the radius of cross-section at height $y$ is $\frac{y}{2}$. Thus our volume is
$$\int_0^{12}\pi\frac{y^2}{4}\,dy.$$
We get $\frac{1000\pi}{12}$, or equivalently $\frac{250\pi}{3}$.

Answer (score 1):

The formula for the volume of a cone of radius $r$ and height $h$ is:

$$V=\frac{1}{3}\pi r^2h$$

Plugging in the values of $r$ and $h$ given in the problem gives a volume of $\frac{250\pi}{3}$.  If you evaluate the integral you wrote, you will get the same number.  Your answer is fine.